# Using backticks or dollar in shell scripts

Tags: command-line

I'm busy writting shell script (using Bash) where I need to populate some variable from the returned result of other command.

So I'm using a syntax like this one :

```
VAR=`command 2>/dev/null`
```

But when looking for information on script shells, I found often that the above can be achieved by using the following syntax too :

```
VAR=$(command 2>/dev/null)
```

Both are working for me (I have received the expected result in both case) and I'm thus wondering if I can still use both form interchangeably or if I have to stick to one form to be sure to stay compliant with the future evolution of shell ?

Comment: See [What's the difference between ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command--command) and  [what is the benefit of using backticks in shell scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed

Comment: The links by belacqua offer a lot of information about the differences and usage. Closing since it is not related to an Ubuntu issue, but more of a programming one. I highly recommended following the links mentioned above.

Answer (score 13):

Use dollar. [Backticks are semi-deprecated](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), because they are more complicated to use (see the link), and there are no advantages to them unless you're doing [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and absolutely need to save a single character. They probably won't be removed from popular shells anytime soon though, so you're safe using either for now.

Answer (score 3):

Stick with the dollar sign notation `$()` whenever you can.  Backticks get cumbersome/confusing when you start needing to do nested quoting.  Ex:

```
$ FOO=`echo "foo's"`
$ echo $FOO
foo's
```

Replacing the backticks with `$()` yields the same output, and is easier to read (fewer quotes of varrying angles to discern):

```
$ FOO=$(echo "foo's")
$ echo $FOO
foo's
```

That, and each quotation mark (single quote, double quote, backtick) means something different in the shell, so using $ can help remove a level of complexity.  And the developer who follows you will thank you, for he/she will have an easier time figuring out what you did.

Comment: Backticks cannot even be nested functionally.

Comment: @Bernhard My example shows what I had in-mind with that statement.