# Setting a randomly generated password to a variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm using the following line to create a randomly generated password in a bash script, but it doesn't look like the string is actually being set to the variable.

```
#Generate random password
PASSWORD=date+%s|sha256sum|base64|head -c 32;
echo $PASSWORD
```

When I reference $PASSWORD later in this script, drush complains that I didn't supply a password. To test, I've tried a few "echoes" to confirm my suspicion. Does it look there's something off in my assignment statements?

Comment: Use syntax `VAR=$(command)`.

Comment: A tip on 'random' things that might be used as a password, check `man mktemp` and note the `--dry-run` option, it is stated as "unsafe" with regard to creating temporary files... but may suit your needs quite well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) quotation, like

```
PASSWORD=`date +%s|sha256sum|base64|head -c 32`
echo $PASSWORD
```

or you can do it as,

```
PASSWORD=$(date +%s|sha256sum|base64|head -c 32)
echo $PASSWORD
```

Comment: The second type is preferred, as it is more visual/visible and also allows nesting to be done easily.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
#Generate random password
PASSWORD=$(date +%s|sha256sum|base64|head -c 32)
echo $PASSWORD
```

then it should work.

Prefer the "$" sign, read more here: [Using backticks or dollar in shell scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487554/using-backticks-or-dollar-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Darn, wish I could mark two answers!

Comment: You can upvote ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Generating a password just based on the current time is quite bad.

As you want a 32-character password, I would do something like this:

```
PASSWORD=$(head -c 16  /dev/random | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d\ )
```

Comment: or just use pwgen

Answer (score 1):

as not having the reputation to comment
I'm forced to add a non answer on this tread

Like @Ángel I was skeptical about generating a password based on time so I did some test

with the command proposed by @Ángel : the password have an average entropy of : **125bits**

with the command **based on time** as proposed by @souravc : the average password entropy is : **175bits**

so it's not that bad to generate a password based on time after all ;)